# why there is a space between the two div under IE7?

Tags: html, css

http://xanlz.com/template/

why there is a space between `<div class="nav-top">...</div>` and `<div class="nav-inner clear"> </div>` (the test navigation part and its below part)  under IE, But ok under firefox and chrome.

how to correct it. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on IE6\IE7 div can't adaptive, so set 'height' for your parent DIV, such as

```
.nav-top { margin-left: 19px; height: 20px;}
```

Comment: +1 This is correct, except my tests show it needs to be height:30px;

Comment: Jason Gennaro， the image's height is 32px. why i can't set it to 32px? it must be set to 30px. if set to 32. there is also an space.